# Junit + Surefire not running the same number of test cases

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have maven's surefire plugin installed for junit.  I have some test suites set up with the following code(stripped to protect the innocent):

```
package com.company.qa.guiauto.test.suites;

import com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.contentcenter.TestClass1;
import com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.contentcenter.TestClass2;
import com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.contentcenter.TestClass3;
import com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.contentcenter.TestClass4;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TestClass1.class, //20 Junit @Tests
        TestClass2.class, //33 Junit @Tests
        TestClass3.class, //4 Junit @Tests
        TestClass4.class  //13 Junit @Tests
})

public class SomeSuite {
}
```

However, when jenkins runs these tests the results are quite variable.  Sometimes it runs 70 tests.  Sometimes 68, sometimes 30.  Can anyone suggest a reason why this would be variably quitting the test run before its actually done?  As you can see here, we have a high of 72 tests, a low of 44 tests, and a last run of 67 tests.  The number of tests has not changed.

[image: TestResult]

Comment: 1) What does the jenkins log say? 2) Maybe a stupid question, but did anyone `@Ignore` some of the failing tests?

Comment: Jenkins log looks basically identical except the missing tests.  There are no @Ignored tests

Comment: You can examine the build which had 72 tests to figure out what the extra tests are. If some tests are executed twice, then it's probably a bug. You can run the tests from command line to see if the behavior persists. You can also notice a revision ID of any build with != 70 tests , checkout to that revision in VCS and carefully compare the list of the tests being executed with actual tests in the project (boring, but useful). You can also manually reduce the # of tests to a reasonable small number (~10?) to make this process easier.

Comment: No exception whatsoever that could explain the sudden test stops? Do you only have JUnit3 or 4 or a combination of both? Have you tried executing maven with -X to see if the correct plugins and dependencies are used?

Comment: See gist for output snippet...note how one test ran 4, but the other one ran 1

https://gist.github.com/llaskin/10398850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the issue.

It was an issue that was fixed in the latest version of Surefire(2.17) in ticket http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-1055.

Upgrading our version of Surefire fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your gist, I can see different test classes being executed in the 2 sessions:

```
Succesful Output File from Jenkins
##Succesful run here.  
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.contentcenter.TestClass1
```

```
Unsuccessful output file
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.company.qa.guiauto.test.regression.test.TestClass1
```